# reason: actual argument Class<ie_home_com> cannot be converted to Class<? extends TestCase> by method invocation conversion

Tags: java, class, junit, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently witing some tests with selenium webdriver using JAVA. And I'm having a problem when trying to execute them. I'll whot you what I got:

- ie_home_com.java

After using javac on it the class is created, ok:

- ie_home_com.java
- ie_home_com.class

Now, I'll be launching the tests from a Nagios via check_nrpe and NSClient++. Because of that, I create a **ie_home.java** file that should launch the class to execute the test. Its content is:

```
import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

public class ie_home_com {

    public static Test suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        suite.addTestSuite(ie_home_com.class);
        return suite;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        junit.textui.TestRunner.run(suite());

    }
}
```

When trying to launch it using **java ie_home.java** in command prompt, I get the following error:

```
C:\SELENIUM\nav\logitravelcom>java ie_home.java
Error: Could not find or load main class ie_home.java
```

And if I try to use **javac** on it I get this:

```
C:\SELENIUM\nav\logitravelcom>javac ie_home.java
ie_home.java:4: error: class ie_home_com is public, should be declared in a file
 named ie_home_com.java
public class ie_home_com {
       ^
ie_home.java:8: error: method addTestSuite in class TestSuite cannot be applied
to given types;
                suite.addTestSuite(ie_home_com.class);
                     ^
  required: Class<? extends TestCase>
  found: Class<ie_home_com>
  reason: actual argument Class<ie_home_com> cannot be converted to Class<? exte
nds TestCase> by method invocation conversion
2 errors
```

What is the problem? I'm very new to Java and can't figure out what the problem is.

Just as a note, my **CLASSPATH** is:

```
C:\SELENIUM\SERVER\junit-4.10.jar;C:\SELENIUM\SERVER\selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar
```

My **PATH** is:

```
%JAVA_HOME%;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

And my **JAVA_HOME** is:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin;C:\SELENIUM\SERVER\junit-4.10.jar;C:\SELENIUM\SERVER\selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar
```

Any help is well appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming your ie_home_com class in ie_home.java to ie_home. The Java compiler expects the file name to be the same as the class name.

Comment: WOW, I feel pretty stupid now. Such a simple thing and problem was solved. Thanks for your help! I would vote up, but I don't have 15 rep. :(